# Bootstrap- How to use horizontal form layout with prepend text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to use horizontal form layout like below:

```
Enter Email: [field]            Enter password: [prepend+field]
```

I've been trying for an hour but couldn't find any solution. Please tell how I can do that.
I have tried:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <!--<span class="offset2">Sign Into the Email</span>-->
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls"><span>Welcome to My Email</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group input-append">
        <label for="emailid"  class="control-label">Email id</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" />
            <span class="add-on">@</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group input-append">
        <label for="passwd" class="control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="password" />
            <span class="add-on">***</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls"  >
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" />Remember Me
            </label>
            <button class="btn">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: float:left; margin-left:20px; should get you started. Providing a jsfiddle might help, though for a more specific answer. [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HcppN/) as an example

Comment: Post the code you've tried please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`form-inline` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

you can use this css to add spacing between the form groups:

```
.form-inline .form-group {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: got it ,how can i provide some spaces b/w two inline fields?